# Changing the style of a PayPal Checkout Button as an Angular.js component?

Tags: angularjs, paypal, paypal-buttons

How do you set the `style` option of the [PayPal Checkout](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout) Button when using it as [Angular.js element](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/frameworks.md#angularjs-element) directive?

```
this.paypal = {
  // ...
  style: {
    color: 'black',
    shape: 'rect'
  }
}
```

It would seem that the `style` option cannot be passed in a binding as `style` as this is already a reserved `HTMLElement` attribute?

```
<paypal-button
  client="$ctrl.paypal.client"
  commit="true"
  env="$ctrl.paypal.env"
  style="$ctrl.paypal.style"
  on-authorize="$ctrl.paypal.onAuthorize"
  on-cancel="$ctrl.paypal.onCancel"
  payment="$ctrl.paypal.payment">
</paypal-button>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it, you have to use `ng-attr-style="$ctrl.paypal.style"` and it will work.

`ng-attr-style` allows you to evaluate an expression instead of interpreting a string literal for the `style` attribute of that input element. The full explanation can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) underneath the heading "ngAttr for binding to arbitrary attributes".

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the [plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/yEHCtnp1GO4oWSVSxROZ?p=preview) for the working code of applying syles over paypalbutton which is inside directive

You can pass the entire paypal variable to the directive inside scope of controller.

```
scope: {
    paypal: '='
},
```

And then you can bind the variable to the template

```
<test-directive paypal="$ctrl.paypal"></test-directive>
```

```js
(function() {
      var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap', 'paypal-button']);
      app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        var $ctrl = this;
        $ctrl.paypal = {
          env: 'sandbox',

          client: {
            sandbox: 'AWi18rxt26-hrueMoPZ0tpGEOJnNT4QkiMQst9pYgaQNAfS1FLFxkxQuiaqRBj1vV5PmgHX_jA_c1ncL',
            production: '<insert production client id>'
          },

          payment: function() {
            var env = this.props.env;
            var client = this.props.client;

            return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
              transactions: [{
                amount: {
                  total: '1.00',
                  currency: 'USD'
                }
              }]
            });
          },

          commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow

          onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

            // Optional: display a confirmation page here

            return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
              // Show a success page to the buyer
            });
          },
          style: {
            color: 'black',
            shape: 'rect'
          }
        };
      }]);
      
      app.directive('testDirective', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<paypal-button env="paypal.env"   style="paypal.style" client="paypal.client"  payment="paypal.payment"  commit="paypal.commit"  on-authorize="paypal.onAuthorize"></paypal-button>',
            scope: {
                paypal: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            }
        };
    }]);
    }());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" data-version-4></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl as $ctrl">
    <test-directive paypal="$ctrl.paypal">
    </test-directive>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was not looking to override the styles of the PayPal Checkout button (which is difficult as its in embedded in the page via an iframe`). I was simply looking for how to set the `style` parameter of the Angular.js component, given `style` is already a valid HTMLElement attribute.